# Keyboard blinking issue in Android input box

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, samsung-mobile

I have created one application using webview. In Webview i have loaded one mvc page. that has two text boxes for getting username and password. While focusing textbox, **textbox and keypad is blinking more** on the Device Samsung Ace GT S5830. `It is working good in IPAD, IPOD, IPHONE and WINDOWS PHONE`. Please anyone tell me how to stop this blinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is the issue with Android. We have workaround for solving this by **setting the below in the AndroidManifest file**.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**Now the keyboard blinking issue is resolved.**

Comment: On what tag should I add this attribute?

Comment: You can add this in activity tag. Refer: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft